# Time in Coulomb's law

Tags: electrostatics

If you have an electric charge somewhere and you make a new  electric charge right now when do these electric charges start to interact with each other?
is it immediately or it take some time ? how much time does it take?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a travelling speed of for electric field? If yes, what is it?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/is-there-a-travelling-speed-of-for-electric-field-if-yes-what-is-it). See also [Does magnetic propagation follow the speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/does-magnetic-propagation-follow-the-speed-of-light)  and [Interaction speed between electric charges and magnetic materials](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27961/interaction-speed-between-electric-charges-and-magnetic-materials)

Comment: We don't know it now. Because we cannot create charge at present. We can just measure speed of changes in electromagnetic fields which is very well explained in above link.